# A little doubt with integral equation

Tags: integral-equations

I have the next equation:
$$\int_{0}^{t}h(\tau)e^{-(t-\tau)}\mathrm{d}\tau=10e^{-t}\cos(4t) \tag{1}$$

Derivating both sides, I get:
$$h(t)e^{-(t-t)}=h(t)=10[(-1)e^{-t}\cos(4t)+e^{-t}(-4)\sin(4t)] \tag{2}$$

However, if first simplify (1) and then derivating:
$$\int_{0}^{t}h(\tau)e^{\tau}\mathrm{d}\tau=10\cos(4t)$$
$$h(t)=10[-4\sin(4t)]e^{-t} \tag{3}$$

Please clarify me what is the correct expression among (2) and (3) and why.

Comment: When you differentiate the integral in (1), you should write it as $e^{-t} \int_0^t h(s) e^s ds$ There should be two terms, $h(t)$ and $-e^{-t} \int_0^t h(s) e^s ds$.

Comment: Because what you are doing is called convolution - from what I understand. Therefore, the process you are trying to do does not apply.

Comment: @copper.hat Are you using the product rule?

Comment: I think that is indeed a use of the product rule. I offered an answer in which this is shown in more detail.

Comment: Yes, the product rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write
$$\int_{0}^{t}h(\tau)e^{-(t-\tau)}d\tau,$$
what is the value of $t$ in the term $e^{-(t-\tau)}$?  Is it the same value of $t$ that is the upper bound of the integral? Does it vary in the same way when you differentiate with respect to $t$?

As I interpret this formula, I see the following identity (with which I see you agree, since the way you "simplify" the formula implies this):
$$\int_{0}^{t}h(\tau)e^{-(t-\tau)}d\tau =
e^{-t} \int_{0}^{t}h(\tau)e^{\tau}d\tau.$$
But
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d}{dt}\left( e^{-t} \int_{0}^{t}h(\tau)e^{\tau}d\tau \right) & = &
 e^{-t} \frac{d}{dt} \left(\int_{0}^{t}h(\tau)e^{\tau}d\tau \right) +
\left(\frac{d}{dt}  e^{-t}\right) \int_{0}^{t}h(\tau)e^{\tau}d\tau \\
& = & e^{-t} (h(t)e^t)  + (- e^{-t}) \int_{0}^{t}h(\tau)e^{\tau}d\tau \\
& = & h(t) - 10e^{-t} \cos(4t)
\end{eqnarray}
which is not equal to $h(t)$ except when $\cos(4t) = 0$.  And oh, look, that term of
$- 10e^{-t} \cos(4t)$ that is missing from your supposed derivative of 
$\int_{0}^{t}h(\tau)e^{-(t-\tau)}d\tau$ is exactly what you need to reconcile the
(corrected) equation $(2)$ with equation $(3)$.

(Note that @copper.hat essentially gave this solution already in a comment on the original question; I am merely spelling it out in more detail.)

Comment: I suppose it accounts for missing $\cos(4t)$ factor (+1) ... I was wondering why eliminating $e^{-t}$ affected it. Also note that $h(0)$ does not seem to be zero.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to differentiate you should check [Differentiation under integral sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign). The integral on left side is known as [Convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) of $h(t)*e^{-t}$ and it's [Laplace transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Example_3.2%3a_Convolution) has very nice form. Try taking Laplace transform on both sides and solve for $h(t)$ using inverse Laplace transform.

Using Laplace transform, I found that the solution to be  $10 (\delta (t)-4 \sin (4 t)+\cos (4 t))$. Note that $h(0)$ isn't zero, you can find that by plugging $t=0$ on both sides where you get $0$ on left but $10$ on right side. While using FTC, it is important to note that you are forgetting to put he lower bound. i.e. $-e^{0}h(0) = -h(0)$. $h(0)$ accounts for $\delta (t)$.

Comment: I checked my calculus book and remember the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. I think that (3) had a correct resolution but I'm not sure.

Comment: The first one can't really be done via FTC Part 1 because the upper bound on the integral is also in the integrand. Let me attempt to explain it using differentiation under the integral sign, if not, I will show a solution using the Laplace transformation.

Comment: I also solved it using Laplace and is interesting the $\delta(t)$ term that is not get using FTC

Comment: @BrallanAguilar
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_0^{\epsilon} h(\tau) e^{-(t-\tau)}d\tau = 10 = 10\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_{0}^{\epsilon} \delta(t) dt$$
since $e^{-(t-\tau)}$ is almost equal to $1$ and $h(t)$ is essentailly $h(0)$, it is only we guess that there should be delta function involved.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution using Differentiation Under the Integral Sign:**

Definition (from the source all knowledge, Wikipedia ;)):
$$\frac{d}{dx}=\left(\int\limits_{a(x)}^{b(x)}{f(x,t)dt}\right)=$$
$$f(x,b(x))*b'(x)-f(x,a(x))a'(x)+\int\limits_{a(x)}^{b(x)}{\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x}dt}$$
If the function doesn't depend on $x$, then we have the simpler solution that is the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus as taught in calculus textbooks, because $\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x}=0$.

In our case, we have the following: $a(t)=0$, $b(t)=t$, $f(t,\tau)=h(\tau)*e^{\tau-t}$. So we are going to now substitute.
$$f(t,t)*(1)-f(t,0)*(0)+\int\limits_0^t {\frac{\partial \left( h(\tau)*e^{\tau-t} \right)}{\partial t}d\tau}$$
The $h(\tau)$ factors out because it is not dependent on $t$ (assumed constant).
$$f(t,t)+\int\limits_0^t {h(\tau) \frac{\partial \left(e^{\tau-t} \right)}{\partial t}d\tau}$$
Take the partial derivative.
$$f(t,t)+\int\limits_0^t {h(\tau)*e^{\tau-t}*(-1)d\tau}$$
Evaluate $f(t,t)$
$$h(t)+\int\limits_0^t {h(\tau)*e^{\tau-t}*(-1)d\tau}$$
Full equality:
$$h(t)-\int\limits_0^t {h(\tau)*e^{\tau-t}*d\tau}=-10e^{-t}\cos(4t)-40e^{-t}\sin(4t)$$
Taking the original definition:
$$h(t)=-10e^{-t}\cos(4t)-40e^{-t}\sin(4t)+\int\limits_0^t {h(\tau)*e^{\tau-t}*d\tau}$$
Substitution:
$$h(t)=-10e^{-t}\cos(4t)-40e^{-t}\sin(4t)+10e^{-t}\cos(4t)$$
Simplify:
$$h(t)=-40e^{-t}\sin(4t)$$
Thus, it appears that your second solution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach (although I generally prefer simpler more straightforward approaches as in David K's answer above):

If $F(t) = \int_0^t f(s,t)ds$, then under appropriate smoothness assumptions we have
$F'(t) = f(t,t) + \int_0^t {\partial f(s,t) \over \partial t } ds$.
This is straightforward to establish using a Taylor expansion.